# Trouble with WorksheetFunction in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to use Workday.Intl function inside a custom function and I am not able to get it work.Find screenshot attached [image]

I researched few questions on WorksheetFunction posted on this forum and tried using some of the suggested fixes but am not able to make it work. Am I doing something wrong? I tried substituting workday instead of Workday.intl but still does not work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably should be:

```
tempdate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl( ...
```

Comment: You can use the object explorer to find out which methods are supported by the WorksheetFunction class. Just hit F2 and look for WorksheetFunction.